# Select result of max of group property

Tags: c#, linq

Thats my code:

```
class Data
{
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
    public int Income { get; private set; }
    public Data(DateTime date, int income)
    {
        Date = date;
        Income = income;
    }
}

public static List<Data> GetSampleData()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now.Date;

    return new List<Data>()
    {
        new Data(now.AddMinutes(-15), 15), //23:45
        new Data(now.AddMinutes(-30), 10), //23:30
        new Data(now.AddMinutes(-45), 7), //23:15
        new Data(now.AddMinutes(-55), 8), //23:05
        new Data(now.AddMinutes(-62), 0), //23:58
        new Data(now.AddMinutes(-67), 12), //22:53
        new Data(now.AddMinutes(-70), 1), //22:50
    };
}
```

I want to get in which hour there highest incomes. With sample data it should gives me result with:

```
Income: 33
Hour: 23
```

What I've manages is this:

```
var data = GetSampleData();

var result = data.GroupBy(x => new
{
    hour = x.Date.Hour
})
.Select(z => new
{
    Sum = z.Sum(a => a.Income),
    Hour = z.Key.hour
})
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Sum)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

This is working. But I dont like my solution because of `OrderByDescending`. Is there any better way to solve this? I would like to have solution with `Max` if possible, but I can't code it. It would be:

`Get max sum of incomes from groups`

Comment: You could use `Aggregate` here.

Comment: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/

Comment: consider accepting answer if it solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Income is 40 :)  SUM(15,10,7,8,0)

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of .NET, [C# 7.0 tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) can be used (the sum has to be the first tuple item) :

```
var result = data.GroupBy(d => d.Date.Hour)
                 .Max(g => (Sum: g.Sum(d => d.Income), Hour: g.Key));
```

or as separate variables :

```
(int Sum, int Hour) = data.GroupBy(d => d.Date.Hour)
                          .Max(g => (g.Sum(d => d.Income), g.Key));
```

---

In older .NET versions, [`System.Tuple<T1,T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2) :

```
var result = data.GroupBy(d => d.Date.Hour)
                 .Max(g => Tuple.Create(g.Sum(d => d.Income), g.Key));
```

If more than one tuple has max sum, result is the tuple with max hour.

---

A tiny bit more efficient alternative without tuple, can be to use same number for both values :

```
int maxSumHour = data.GroupBy(d => d.Date.Hour)
                     .Max(g => g.Sum(d => d.Income) * 100 + g.Key));

int Sum = maxSumHour / 100, Hour = maxSumHour % 100;
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking this works because when comparing the tuples it compares each individual element in order or similar?

Comment: @Chris yes, so the sum has to be the first tuple item. If more than one hour has max sum, result is the tuple with max hour

Comment: Cool. I figure it might be worth putting that in the answer since I don't reckon that is behaviour that everybody will be totally familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aggregate:

```
    .Aggregate( (curMax, x) => (curMax == null) || (x.Sum > curMax.Sum) ? x : curMax );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is fine in my opinion, given that you can have more than one hour with the same max income. That being said, you can always use `Aggregate`:

```
var sums = data.GroupBy(d => d.Date.Hour)
           .Select(g => new { hour = g.Key, sum = g.Sum(d => d.Income) });
var maxData = sums.Aggregate(
              sums.FirstOrDefault(), //First parameter
              (max, next) => next.sum > max.sum ? next : max, //Second parameter
              sum => sum //Third parameter
              );
```

**Explanation:**

1. The first part is the same. You group by hour then select the hour and the sum.
2. The `Aggregate` function uses a seed as the first parameter, which in this case is the first item of the sums.
3. The next expression is a function that compares the sums and picks up the greater one recursively.
4. The last parameter picks the result to return.

If you inspect `maxData`, it will the aggregate type with properties `hour` and `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a Solution with Max(), just dont use an anonymous type, but create a class/struct first and implement IComparable

```
    public struct IncomePerHour : IComparable<IncomePerHour>
    {
        public int Income { get; set; }
        public int Hour { get; set; }
        public int CompareTo(IncomePerHour other)
        {
            return Income.CompareTo(other.Income); 
        }
    }
```

Then, instead of using the anonymous result of your select, make it the class/struct you just created.

```
       var data = GetSampleData();
        var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Hour)
       .Select(z => new IncomePerHour
       {
           Income = z.Sum(a => a.Income),
           Hour = z.Key
       })
       .Max();
```

And if you want to reuse your Data:

```
    public class Data : IComparable<Data>
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
        public int Income { get; private set; }
        public Data(DateTime date, int income)
        {
            Date = date;
            Income = income;
        }

        public int CompareTo(Data other)
        {
            return Income.CompareTo(other.Income);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        var data = GetSampleData();
        var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Date.Hour)
       .Select(z => new Data (z.First().Date, z.Sum(a => a.Income)))
       .Max();

        Console.WriteLine($"Hour: {result.Date.Hour}, Income:{result.Income}");
    }
```

Comment: hi, did it help?